# Grabbing extra (chained) method calls into __get() magic-method

Tags: php

I don't have high hopes for this one:

Given a service that has an action like the `foo` in `$service->foo->bar( $a, $b )` and a container class that has `$service` as a protected property, is there a way to use `__get()` on the container to access the service and pass along the `->bar( $a, $b )`?

```
class Container {
  protected $service;
  protected $responses = [];

  public function __get ($name) {
    $this->responses[] = $service->$name-> _???_
    return $resp;
  }
}
```

that could be intercepted so that the Container could catch the operation, call `$service` with it, save the response, then return the response

Either some way to grab whatever else is being chained on the `$name` or if `$name` just included all of that. I know this is a little convoluted, but it would help me clean some code up substantially, plus I'm just generally curious now.

This app is running PHP7 if that matters.

And alternately, if there *is* a way to do this but it isn't `__get()`, insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `bar` takes place after `__get` returned. `__get` is called by the engine so you can't add additional parameters. However you can create additional methods on your container class to implement the feature you want.

Assuming I understood your question correctly this would result in something like this:

```
public function executeOnService(string $name, string $method, ...$args) {
    return call_user_func_array([$this->service->$name, $method], $args);
}
```

Comment: That's probably the most sane way of doing it. What I was hoping for was to perfectly re-create the syntax of the actual call, just redirected through the Container. Doesn't seem possible, though. Drat.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already expect the consumer code of your `Container` to know a lot about the properties of this service object, perhaps you should just consider returning the property of the service that the consuming code wants to act upon, e.g.:

```
public function __get ($name) {
  return $service->$name;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to handle the action within the container, store the result in the container, and *also* return the result. So there will be chained methods on the end of `$service->$name`, but I don't think I have any way to access those from within the `__get()`